# Remove bad characters to file name while spliting with awk

Tags: awk, sh

I have a large file that I split with awk, using the last column as the name for the new files, but one of the columns include a "/", which gives can't open error.

I have tried make a function to transform the name for the file but awk don't use it when I run it, maybe a error from part:

```
tried_func() {
 echo $1 | tr "/" "_"
}


awk -F ',' 'NR>1 {fname="a_map/" tried_func $NF".csv"; print >> fname; 
close(fname)}' large_file.csv
```

Large_file.csv

```
A,        row,    I don't,  need
plenty,   with,   columns,  good_name
alot,     off,    them,     another_good_name
more,     more,   more,     bad/name
```

expected res:

list of file i a_map:

- good_name.csv
- another_good_name.csv
- bad_name.csv

actual res:

```
awk: can't open file a_map/bad/name.csv
```

Don't need to be a function, if I can just skip the "/" in awk that is fab too.

Comment: As an aside, you mean `echo "$1"`.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk is not part of the shell, it's an independent programming language, so you can't call shell functions that way. Instead, just do the whole thing within awk:

```
$ awk -F ',' '
NR>1 {
    gsub(/\//,"_",$NF)          # replace /s with _s 
    fname="a_map/" $NF ".csv"
    print >> fname
    close(fname)
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks, I hoped it was something easy like that! Works like a charm! Didn't know it was its own language either! Good to know since it's awesome for what I do.